# T-SQL: select top 20 root nodes with children

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My situation: I have a table in a SQL Server 2012 database

```
id | created             | sum
------------------------------
1  | 2013-12-10 12:00:00 | 200 
2  | 2013-12-10 13:00:00 | 300 
3  | 2013-12-10 14:00:00 | 400 
4  | 2013-12-09 08:00:00 | 100 
5  | 2013-12-09 15:00:00 | 600 
6  | 2013-12-10 12:00:00 | 50 
...
50 | 2013-11-23 14:00:00 | 400 
51 | 2013-11-22 08:00:00 | 100 
52 | 2013-11-22 15:00:00 | 600 
53 | 2013-11-20 12:00:00 | 50
```

How can I select rows for 20 different dates **without taking into account the time**?

Expected result of select operation:

```
1 | 2013-12-10
1  | 2013-12-10 12:00:00 | 200 
2  | 2013-12-10 13:00:00 | 300 
3  | 2013-12-10 14:00:00 | 400 
2 | 2013-12-09
4  | 2013-12-09 08:00:00 | 100 
5  | 2013-12-09 15:00:00 | 600 
...
20| 2013-11-22
51 | 2013-11-22 08:00:00 | 100 
52 | 2013-11-22 15:00:00 | 600
```

Comment: I don't see an attempt?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I've no idea how to do it

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using? In **2008** and newer, you can use the `DATE` datatype which is date-only, e.g. by casting your `DATETIME` to a `DATE` and then using that date-only portion to select

Comment: @marc_s: SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

- have a CTE (Common Table Expression) extract the 20 date-only values from your table
- join your base table against the CTE output to get all the rows from the base table, for those selected dates only

Try something like this:

```
-- replace this with your own, base table - this is just for demo purposes
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, Created DATETIME2(0), ValueSum INT)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES(1, '2013-12-10 12:00:00', 200), 
(2, '2013-12-10 13:00:00', 300 ), 
(3, '2013-12-10 14:00:00', 400),  
(4, '2013-12-09 08:00:00', 100 ), 
(5, '2013-12-09 15:00:00', 600),  
(6, '2013-12-10 12:00:00', 50),  
(50, '2013-11-23 14:00:00', 400 ), 
(51, '2013-11-22 08:00:00', 100 ), 
(52, '2013-11-22 15:00:00', 600 ), 
(53, '2013-11-20 12:00:00', 50 )

-- define a CTE thta selects TOP (n) distinct date-only values from your base table    
;WITH RandomDates AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (3)
        DateOnly = CAST(Created AS DATE)
    FROM @table
)
SELECT * FROM RandomDates
```

This will list your chosen date-only values

If you join those values against your base table, you might get your output wanted...

```
;WITH RandomDates AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (20)
        DateOnly = CAST(Created AS DATE)
    FROM dbo.YourBaseTable
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM RandomDates rd
INNER JOIN dbo.YourBaseTable t ON CAST(t.Created AS DATE) = rd.DateOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT rowNo, createdDate, sumCol
FROM ( SELECT TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, a.created)) rowNo, CONVERT(DATE, a.created) createdDate, '' sumCol
       FROM tableA a
       GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, a.created)
       UNION 
       SELECT B.id AS rowNo, b.created AS createdDate, b.sum AS sumCol
       FROM (SELECT TOP 20 CONVERT(DATE, a.created) createdDate FROM tableA a ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, a.created)) A
       INNER JOIN tableA B ON A.createdDate = CONVERT(DATE, b.created)
      ) AS A
ORDER BY createdDate
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bd97/2)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ROWNO |         CREATEDDATE | SUMCOL |
|-------|---------------------|--------|
|     1 | 2013-11-20 00:00:00 |      0 |
|    53 | 2013-11-20 12:00:00 |     50 |
|     2 | 2013-11-22 00:00:00 |      0 |
|    51 | 2013-11-22 08:00:00 |    100 |
|    52 | 2013-11-22 15:00:00 |    600 |
|     3 | 2013-11-23 00:00:00 |      0 |
|    50 | 2013-11-23 14:00:00 |    400 |
|     4 | 2013-12-09 00:00:00 |      0 |
|     4 | 2013-12-09 08:00:00 |    100 |
|     5 | 2013-12-09 15:00:00 |    600 |
|     5 | 2013-12-10 00:00:00 |      0 |
|     1 | 2013-12-10 12:00:00 |    200 |
|     6 | 2013-12-10 12:00:00 |     50 |
|     2 | 2013-12-10 13:00:00 |    300 |
|     3 | 2013-12-10 14:00:00 |    400 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Slower

```
select top 20 distinct CONVERT(varchar(25), Created, 110)
from    tbl
where   CONVERT(varchar(25), Created, 110) between [Datfrom] and [DateTo]
```

Faster

```
select top 10 distinct CONVERT(varchar(25), Created, 110)
from    tbl
where   Created between '1/1/2013' + ' 00:00:00' and '1/31/2013' + ' 23:59:59'
```

Comment: If you specify dates as string, you should always use the **ISO-8601** format (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`) to avoid issues with different language/regional settings... `1/31/2013` would be interpreted as "1st of the 31st month" in most European language settings, for instance ....

Comment: I just show the date as string but you can also use a datetime variable that contain the proper format of the date according to your region.